# Changing specific records into columns in Pnadas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a data like below:-

```
     name      date              groupby_count
     abc       2019-12-10          20
     abc       2019-12-05          42
     pqr       2019-12-08          55
     pqr       2019-12-05          10
     xyz       2019-12-10          100
     xyz       2019-12-06          200
```

I want it ike below:

```
     name   2019-12-05   2019-12-06   2019-12-08   2019-12-10
     abc      42             0           0             20
     pqr      10             0           55            0
     xyz      0             200          0             100
```

I tried ONE hot encoding & get_dummies, but I guess those are not what is required. can anyone please help?

Comment: @jezrael, I am not sure if this post has the answer

Comment: `df = df.pivot('name','date','groupby_count')`